# Questions about Rasterization: Stochastic Sampling, Pineda Edge Function and Fixed Point Numbers

Tags: c++, cgi, rendering, rasterizing

I am trying to study/understand the rasterization algorithm and have already posted a few posts which are related to this and unfortunately didn't get many answers:

[Rasterisation Algorithm: finding the "ST" coordinates of point in 2D quad and Inverse Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012828/rasterisation-algorithm-finding-the-st-coordinates-of-point-in-2d-quad-and-in)

In the first question I wanted to rasterize a quad, but now I will limit myself to a triangle which is the standard rendering prim anyway.

So my problem at the problem is to know exactly which technique is used to find if a given pixel is in a triangle. I have been using the edge function approach which is okay. Let's say I need to loop over all pixels of a bbox surrounding a 2D Triange.

```
float dX0 = (v1.x - v0.x);
float dY0 = (v1.y - v0.y);
float dX1 = (v2.x - v1.x);
float dY1 = (v2.y - v1.y);
float dX2 = (v0.x - v2.x);
float dY2 = (v0.y - v2.y);
for (int y = ymin; y <= ymax; ++y) {
    for (int x = xmin; x <= xmax; ++x) {
        float xctr = x + 0.5;
        float yctr = y + 0.5;
        float s0 = (xctr - v0.x) * dX0 - (yctr - v0.y) * dY0;
        float s1 = (xctr - v1.x) * dX1 - (yctr - v1.y) * dY1;
        float s2 = (xctr - v2.x) * dX2 - (yctr - v2.y) * dY2;

        if (s0 >= 0 && s1 >= 0 && s2 >= 0) {
             // point is in triangle
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to the barycentric approach. Compute s and t for the point in the triangle and if (s + t) <= 1 then I know the point is in the triangle.

So from there I have several questions:

1) In the paper from [Pineda [88]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.157.4621&rep=rep1&type=pdf) though it is said that if you move along x or y you can simply update the result of the edge function with a simple addition. I quote:

```
The edge functions may then be computed incrementally for a unit step in the X or Y direction:
Ei(x+l,y)=Ei(x,y)+dYi,
Ei(x-1,y)=Ei(x,y)-dYi,
Ei(x,y+l)=Ei(x,y)-dXi,
Ei(x,y-l)=Ei(x,y)+dXi.
```

So that's okay I understand why this works, but in the general case where the we do super sampling or even stochastic sampling (dividing the pixel into say 4x4 samples which are jittered) would that method still be beneficial at all?

2) I still don't know how with the edge function we can compute s/t/z by interpolation? Could someone help me with this or indicate me some pages in which this is explained?

3) Now I studying other approach for rasterizing triangles, such as the Bresenham algorithm, but it seems to say everywhere that it only works on fixed point coordinates? I am confused. After projection triangles vertices are in floating points. How can you go from float point to fixed point coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### RASTERIZATION

First of all, a typical rasterization algorithm won't iterate over the whole bounding box of the projected triangle like what you are attempting, because that would be way too slow.
The idea is to:

- project vertices to image space,
- order 2D vertices either horizontally or vertically (preferably using the direction of the smaller bounding box dimension)
- split the triangle in two:

  - from first vertex to vertical or horizontal passing though second vertex,
  - from vertical/horizontal passing through second vertex to third vertex,
- rasterize each half

You would get something looking like this:

```
           * v2
          /|\
         / | \
        /  |  \
       / T1|T2 \
   v1 *----+----* v3
```

Now, for rasterizing triangle T1, you can have X iterate from v1.x to v2.x and use the slope of edges to compute the range over which Y should iterate for the triangle slice at X.

The bounds of this Y-range will have constant increments for each vertical slice, so you can either represent those increments as fractional numbers (either fixed or floating-point) or use the Bresenham algorithm.

The idea is the same for triangle T2.

#### MULTISAMPLING

When doing multisampling with jittered samples, you would decide if each individual sample lies within the triangle doing basically what you attempted, *but* that is only necessary for pixels at the edge of the triangle.

However, texture lookup only need to happen once for each pixel (covering multiple samples).

If you want to compute depth at each sample, the per-pixel depth increment basically has to be multiplied by the fractional jitter of the sample from pixel's centroid.

#### INTERPOLATING TEXTURE COORDINATES

Now if we consider the rasterization algoithm, it can be thought that each increment in either X or Y translates into an increment in S, T and Z. That basically works OK but causes distortions because linear interpolation of S, T, Z does not account for depth-division.

Rather than trying to convert image-space coordinates back to 3D scene coordinates, it's possible (and cheaper) to compute corrected S, T, Z from the naively computed ones.

You can check out this PDF to find the formula for the correction factor:
[http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/s12/perspectiveCorrect.pdf](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Eamenta/s12/perspectiveCorrect.pdf)

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you. That should be enough to start experimenting with your ideas, suggestion. I am yet to find information about converting vertex pos to fixed point but I believe I found something already. Brilliant. Thank you for taking the time to elaborate.